# Why is the cloud code function not being called in the iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to get the title and artist from a certain user using cloud code. I have a pointer to the user class in the Pointer class. I am trying to get all the title and artists (strings) matched to the current user. For some reason the cloud code is not executing, I am not getting anything in the iOS log. I think the cloud code is working, but I feel I am missing something to send the data back to the iOS app.

iOS code

```
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("search", withParameters: ["user": currentUserID!]) {
        (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
            if let objects = response as? [PFObject]{
                for object in objects{
                    print(object)
                }
            }
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("search", function(request, response){
var review = Parse.Object.extend("Pointer")
var query = new Parse.Query(review)
var userPointer = {
__type: 'Pointer',
className: '_User', // name of class
objectId: request.params.user
}
console.log(userPointer);
query.equalTo("user", userPointer);
console.log(query.equalTo("user", userPointer));
query.find().then(function(results){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
        sum += results[i].get("title");
        sum += results[i].get("artist")
    }
    response.success(sum / results.length);
}, function(error){
    response.error(error)
});
});
```

Comment: is the id for the current user? if so the user object is passed to the cloud code so you don't need to pass an additional parameter or try to create a pointer (faux user object)

Comment: Yes, the id is the current user. I tried doing that but I kept getting the error that I need a pointer object to query through the pointer column. I don't get that error anymore, but I feel I need to print the results. How would I do that?

Comment: Try using `console.log("results = " + JSON.stringify(results));` to print it out

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about the way you're creating a user pointer but in the past I've used this: `var userPointer = new Parse.User();` `userPointer.id = request.params.user;`. You may also want to check if results.length is 0 before dividing.

Comment: When I do the console.log I get results but how do I get that data in my iOS App?

Comment: Your code is misleading. What is the purpose of `sum` and why are you returning a number when in the OP you mentioned wanting to return all of the titles/authors? Since this cloud function is just performing a basic query, why not perform the query client side?